# JSR 303 validation message override @Id - can't find bundle exception

Tags: java, jsf, bean-validation

I'm trying to create a customize messages.properties file for bean validation messages.
I added a `Messages.properties` file into resource package, and added `<application><message-bundle>resources.Messages</message-bundle></application>` to my `faces-config.xml` file.

I'm validating an entity which have a primary key field and have the `@Id` annotation (javax.persistence.Id).

when I override messages like `javax.faces.converter.BigDecimalConverter.DECIMAL` it works greate, but my problem when this input is empty I get the exception message: `Can't find bundle for base name resources.Messages, locale en_US`.

I have also a message for this kind of validation - which is `javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED` in the properties file (so it's not that i'm missing the correct message text).

so I tried adding into the `faces-config.xml` file the locale config: `<locale-config>
<default-locale>en_US</default-locale></locale-config>` , and also added another properties file which called: Messages_en_US.properties into the resorce package,
but I still get the exception.

What could be the problem? am I missing somthing? how can this be resolved? 
is this problem caused because of the @Id annotation? can I get pass it?
I want to be able to see my custom message.
I tried every thing I could think of, but didn't get it to work, Please help!!

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: First of all you are not using Bean Validation (JSR 303). You are using JSF built in validation. Secondly @Id has nothing to do with validation. I don't use JSF validation but I think that `javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED` message is shown only in the case of required="true" in facelet. Are you sure that your bundle is in /WEB-INF/classes/resources/ folder? Are you sure that you can override `javax.faces.converter.BigDecimalConverter.DECIMAL` correctly?

Comment: @Alf: why not using bean validation? I have no tags of validators inside my jsf page. as far as I know `@Size` , `@NotNull` , `@Max` etc.. are bean validation and not jsf. the only jsf validator I used was required=true, and i tried adding after it didn't work, so I'm not really using it, just tested it. yes I'm sure about both things, I can see the file in the path, and I can see `javax.faces.converter.BigDecimalConverter.DECIMAL` error message, Any ideas?

Comment: Your setup is not related to Bean Validation. As you can see `javax.faces.converter.BigDecimalConverter.DECIMAL` is a jsf error. If you want to override bean validation messages you have to add a ValidationMessages_xx.properties in WEB-IF/classes folder. Anyhow I don't understand why in some cases jsf localize the message bundle and is some other not.

Answer (score -1):

Just place those properties file inside the source folder as the same structure as it is in the WEB-INF resource folder,the java class will get the reference from the java resources folder.

Try this, I also faced the same problem, it works for me.

Comment: placing everything inside src folder is simple but not adviced. every application has a structure and its betther to organise. rather than copying everything on src , try to get what is needed on claspath.